# Android | Cannot access to respectively save on [/storage/emulated/0/]

Tags: android

Having following issue during backup/writing on storage in my app. It crashes when trying to backup. Usually all data and settings of the app are saved in realm.backup and zipped.
Storage location is /storage/emulated/0/my_Backup

Android: >=11 (with 9 it works)
TargetSDK: >29 (with 29 it works)

Looks like the access rights to the storage have been changed for SDK > 29 / Android 11. I haven't been able to find a solution yet. "Context" is mentioned in Android [descriptions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific), but it didn't work for me (if I adjusted it correctly).

Had someone had similar problems and already solved them?

**Error Message**

```
Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException
Unable to open a realm at path '/storage/emulated/0/myApp/backup.realm': open() failed: Operation not permitted. (open("/storage/emulated/0/myApp/backup.realm") failed: Operation not permitted) (/storage/emulated/0/myApp/backup.realm) in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 407
```

**my Backup Code**

```
public void backup() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        private SweetAlertDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new SweetAlertDialog(activity, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
            dialog.setContentText(activity.getString(R.string.settings_do_backup));
            dialog.setTitleText("");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            File exportRealmFile;

            exportRealmFile = new File(Utils.getStorageDir(), EXPORT_REALM_FILE_NAME);
            exportRealmFile.delete();
            realm.writeCopyTo(exportRealmFile);

            File zipFile = new File(Utils.getStorageDirForBackup(), "backup_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".zip");
            zipFile.delete();

            File wholeDirectory = new File(Utils.getStorageDir()+"/");

            ZipUtil.pack(wholeDirectory, zipFile);

            exportRealmFile.delete();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            Settings.getSettings(realm).setLastBackup(new Date());
            realm.commitTransaction();


            realm.close();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();

            
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            alertBuilder
                    .setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.settings_backup_stored))
                    .setNeutralButton(activity.getString(R.string.generell_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

**my Util Code**

```
public static String getStorageDirForBackup(){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_Backup";
    File f = new File(path);
    f.mkdirs();
    return f.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

**my backup code (updated)**

```
if (Utils.getStorageDirForBackup()==null) ....  ?
File zipFile = new File(Utils.getStorageDirForBackup(),
"backup_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".zip");
```

**my Util Code (updated)**

```
public static String getStorageDirForBackup(){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_Backup";
    File f = new File(path);
    if(!f.exists()) if(!f.mkdirs()) return null;
    return f.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: `if(!f.exists()) if(!f.mkdirs()) return null;`

Comment: so, you mean... if(!f.exists()) f.mkdirs(); if(!f.mkdirs()) return null; ?

Comment: Noooooo. My god... read my comment and copy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But where should the line go exactly? Should it be before mkdirs, after, or replace it? I'm not a professional! Otherwise I wouldn't ask here. I've tried all the variants, I now get the following message:
////
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/backup.realm'. Please use a path where your app has read-write permissions. (open("/backup.realm") failed: Read-only file system) (/backup.realm) in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 407 Kind: PERMISSION_DENIED.

Comment: You should replace `f.mkdirs();` with it.

Comment: `File zipFile = new File(Utils.getStorageDirForBackup(),.....` You should not blindly call getStorageDirForBackup() as it might return null; as you know know. So call it first and check if it returns null.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it. See my original post, marked as "updated". Unfortunately, I couldn't finish the zip file. I tried everything possible, but it didn't work out. What should the code be?

Comment: `if (Utils.getStorageDirForBackup()==null) ....  ?` Well then you should stop and display a Toast() to the user saying that you could not force a needed directory.

Comment: Yes, that's how I did it. But the toast is not called at all because the realm is apparently already accessed beforehand. Same error message as above: ```**Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/backup.realm'```